# Evaluate $\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{z-5}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

> $$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{z-5}dz$$

That can only be solved using Cauchy's integral formula?

$$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}$$

where $f(z)=f(z_0)=1$

So we get $${2\pi i}=\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{z-5}dz$$

Comment: That is wrong. Is the pole $5$ inside the circle $|z|=2$?

Comment: @RobertZ Right $z_0=5$ is not in the domain

Comment: @RobertZ My bad, we should use Cauchy's integral theorem and because it is a closed curve with the function is analytic we will get $0$

Comment: Yes, so that integral is zero.

Comment: The integrand is holomorphic within the region, so...

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The integrand $f(z)=\frac1{z-5}$ is clearly holomorphic on the region $|z|\le2\dots$

[MPW pointed this out first](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324911/evaluate-int-z-2-frac1z-5dz/2324945#comment4785870_2324911).

Comment: @gbox: have you abandoned your question and do you want to accept an existent useful answer?  +1